# Getting aspect ratio fo image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am appending an image to a div like this:

> $thisComp.find('.DummyImage').attr("src", this.imageUrl);

in the line after this I am using ajax call and getting the aspect ratio of the image like this:

> $.ajax(this.imageUrl).done(function () {
>               var AspectRatio = ($thisComp.find('.DummyImage').width() / $thisComp.find('.DummyImage').height()).toFixed(2);

In this case I am getting sometimes correct value aspect ratio and sometimes NaN (specifically in Chrome browser) in other browsers it is alway working fine.
I think the problem is in the ajax call is getting executed first before even the line above it completely loads the "src" image.

Please suggest the possible solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wait for the load event of the image instead of loading the image using `$.ajax`. These are 2 separate requests!

```
var $img = $thisComp.find('.DummyImage');
.on("load", function() {
    alert($img.width() / $img.height());
})
.attr("src", this.imageUrl);
```